# Can a parallel pool be started asynchronously?

Tags: matlab, asynchronous, parallel-processing

When a MATLAB parallel pool is started for the first time it typically takes a few seconds. In a user-interactive application there is hence an incentive to make sure there is a parallel pool running before the first demand for computational tasks arrives, so the process of starting a parallel pool isn't added to the total time to respond to the request.

However every programmatic action such as `parpool` that I've seen that will start a parallel pool blocks execution until the pool is done starting up. This means even if the user has no need to call upon the parallel pool for some time, they cannot do anything else like begin setting up their computationally expensive request – filling in a user interface for instance – until the parallel pool is done starting.

This is very frustrating! If it was *any other* time-consuming preparatory action, once a parallel pool was in place it could be done in the background using `parfeval` and wouldn't obstruct the user's workflow until any request that actually called upon the completion of that preparation. But because this task actually *addresses* the lack of a running parallel pool, it seems users must wait for something they may not actually need to use until long after the task is complete.

Is there any way around this apparent limitation on usability?

Comment: I don't think so no. MATLAB is not asyncronous itself.

Comment: @AnderBiguri the synchronicity of the main MATLAB thread is not obviously an outright obstacle. Operations *on* the parallel pool and graphics drawing actions are two examples of asynchronous tasks that be initiated by synchronous actions on that thread. I can't think of a way to accomplish this particular one either, but that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean, but I still think the answer is "no".

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've seen you around here enough to know that you know what is and isn't an answer :)

Comment: I don't know the real answer, so I don't want to post one, or make any total claim, but if I understand right, to be able to do what you want you would need to be able to change the way MATLAB (the software, not the language) behaves. MATLAB has implemented on the software, the ability to do graphics on a separate thread, for example. But this is not something you as an user can touch, its part of the proprietary software. You can not change that and make MATLAB compute graphics only when its doing X code or Y code, that is not possible. I think its the same with `parpool`

Comment: @AnderBiguri the slow bit of `parpool` does *not* appear to occur on the main thread though. Most of the time that it hogs control of execution is spent waiting for workers to respond after being started. That leave open (even if only theoretically with no practical solution) the possibility that there are other ways outside of `parpool` to getting that work done without blocking execution on the all-important MATLAB main thread.

Comment: What you say makes sense and seems indeed engineeringly plausible! I still lean towards the "no", but I really hope I am wrong, because I have myself been annoyed by this several times :)

Comment: @AnderBiguri likewise - if nothing else, the absence of good answers to a recurring common annoyance does, in and of itself, merit a discoverable Q&A question for others to land on while trying to learn if an answer does exist!

Comment: I agree with that! You already have my upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MATLAB R2021b the addition of [`backgroundPool`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.backgroundpool.html) is a more appropriate solution for most computational work that needs to be done in the background. It doesn't access all the same functionality as actually starting a pool of parallel workers (which still cannot be done in the background as far as I can see) but for the stated use case of creating a responsive user-interactive interface it is ideal for eliminating most interface delays.

Comment: Indeed, this is nice new functionality. For older versions of MATAB, `parpool('Threads')` should be faster, as it doesn’t spin up background MATLAB sessions. The other alternative is to spin up the parallel pool during startup, people are used to an application taking some time to load.

Comment: Note that `backgroundPool` and `parpool('Threads')` are both thread-based pools. Per the doc https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.backgroundpool.html they share resources which in practice means that once one of them has been created, the other can be created almost instantaneously. (Also, thread pool startup time should have improved quite a bit since R2021b hopefully).

Comment: @Edric this helps explain why I didn't find `parpool('Threads')` to solve much when I asked the question originally I think! It is now very fast indeed compared to anything I recall trying back in 2020...

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to launch a parallel pool in the background. There are a couple of potential mitigations that might help:

1. Don't ever explicitly call `parpool` - just let the auto-creation of the pool only start creating the pool when you hit a parallel language construct such as `parfor`, `parfeval`, or `spmd`.
2. If you're using a cluster which might not be able to service your request for workers for some time, you could use [`batch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/batch.html) to launch the whole computation in the background. (This is probably only appropriate if you've got a fairly long-running computation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Given your area of expertise within MathWorks I'll have to grudgingly accept this is currently an unavoidable limitation, though I might privately hope there's some undocumented trick out there that you're not willing to signpost publicly ;)